# PHP capture value of multiple-nested array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

My server response looks like this:

```
[results] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [addresses] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [physical_address] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [street_line1] => 302 Baggins Dr
                                        [street_line2] => Apt 5
                                        [locality] => Allen
                                        [region] => TX
                                        [postal_code] => 75015
                                    )
```

I need to capture "street_line1" in a variable like so:

```
$address1 = ($response["results"][$i]["addresses"]["physical_address"]["street_line1"]);
```

But I cannot work it out. I am getting:

```
Notice: Undefined index: physical_address
```

What am I missing?

Comment: addresses is an array of _objects_ (as are other items). So it should be `$response["results"][$i]->adresses[0]->physical_address->street_line1`

Comment: It's not only an array, it's mixed data, object within array, To access object you can use `->` arrow sign or to access array you can use `[]` square brackets.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. Still not working though :(  I am getting:
Notice: Trying to get property 'addresses' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\IMPORT\IMPORT-get.CC.tokens.php on line 48

Notice: Trying to get property 'physical_address' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\IMPORT\IMPORT-get.CC.tokens.php on line 48

Notice: Trying to get property 'street_line1' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\IMPORT\IMPORT-get.CC.tokens.php on line 48

Comment: I'm getting 1st-level values easy enough, like this:    $firstname = ($data["results"][$i]["first_name"]);

Comment: @James then the shown structure is not the one you actually got. The new errors indicate that it's all arrays. Then it would be `$response["results"][$i]["addresses"][0]["physical_address"]["street_line1"]` (there's one `[0]` more in the middle).

Comment: @Jeff with that I get 'Notice: Undefined index: physical_address'

Comment: $address1 = $response["results"][$i]["addresses"][0]["physical_address"]["street_line1"];

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but here is how I am creating objects:
    $params = array (
 'first_name' => $firstname,
 'last_name' => $lastname,
 'company_name' => str_replace(",","",$companyname),
 'customer_id' => $customer_id,
 'addresses' => array ( 
  array (
   'first_name' => $firstname,
   'last_name' => $lastname,
   'address_type' => 'default_billing',
   'physical_address' => array (
    'street_line1' => $address1,
    'street_line2' => $address2,
    'locality' => $city,
    'region' => $state,
    'postal_code' => $zipcode
   )
  )
 ),

Comment: @Jeff my bad. Had a glitch in my code. You got the right answer but I don't see where to mark it "answered". Thanks for your help.

Comment: ..because I didn't write an answer yet. And I wouldn't know which version would be the right answer...

Comment: This did the trick:    $address1 = $response["results"][$i]["addresses"][0]["physical_address"]["street_line1"];